# How to ecr describe-repositories from another account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecr

In an ec2 instance with role-based authentication, I want to read the list of all docker images available in a different account.

I can do
`aws ecr --region <my_region> describe-repositories`

But that gives me the repositories in **my** account.
I set up a policy to allow describe-repositories over a **different** account, but I don't know how to pass the account id to the aws ecr command.

Comment: "set up a policy" what policy? Where? Sadly your question lacks details and is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
aws ecr describe-repositories --registry-id <ecr-registry-account-no> --repository-names <repo-name>
```

If your repo policy is set correctly(`ecr:DescribeRepositories`), it should work.

Comment: Adding `--registry-id <ecr-registry-account-no>` to my command worked.

Comment: This works, but I'm wondering if anyone has found a way to list all repos from another account. I don't see this being possible since these policies are at the repo level. Any suggestions there? `aws ecr describe-repositories --registry-id`